# Convert a vector into a csv file

Tags: qgis

Is it possible to use QGIS to convert a vector that contains points/polygons into a csv file and, if yes, in which way?

Comment: Questions in GIS SE are expected to have only one question. Please edit to focus on your most pressing question; the other can be asked in another question.

Comment: csv files are usually a means for data exchange between softwares and definitely not recommended  for what what you are asking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MMQGIS plugin is able to export vector data to a CSV file.

I usually use semicolon as CSV delimiter. In the delimited text import dialogue, make sure that no other separator is checked.

BTW the MMQGIS plugin can import **and** export from/to CSV.

Comment: Thank you!!! It worked with MMQGIS plugin and it's function to export geometry into a csv file:)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `Save As...` option by right-clicking the layer and select the format to `CSV`.

You can also decide to keep geometries of your features by setting the *Layer Options* (e.g. you can use `AS_XY` to keep the X and Y coordinates for, say, a point layer).

Comment: Thanks, just tryed.. The problem is that mmqgis gives me this error "Bad CSV file - verify that your delimiters are consistent" when trying to add the csv file, I need that plugin to join a layer and a csv by attribute

Comment: If the geometries are exported using Well-Known Text, linestring and polygon types will contain commas -- try delimiting with `|` instead.

Comment: I get the same error even with I